# How do i use Foundation 5 reveal model in a link_to in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

This is the example that Foundation gives me.

```
 <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Click Me For A Modal</a>

 <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
  <h2>Awesome. I have it.</h2>
  <p class="lead">Your couch.  It is mine.</p>
  <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
 </div>
```

This is my link

```
 <%= link_to "watch", video %>
```

What i want it when i click on that link i want my videos/show page to show or the video in that show page. Im not sure how to use the data-reveal-id in a link_to in rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "watch", video, data: {:"reveal-id" => "myModal", :"reveal-ajax" => true} %>
```

Comment: By any chance do you know how to make another page show rather then only the text in the same page show? I have the link_to in my home/index page and i have the other half in my videos/show page.

Comment: @Wesly, see my edits above. Consult the [Foundation docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html) for more information.